# Difficulties with jQuery AJAX operation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm making a username checker that takes POST data and sends it to a PHP script which creates a simple array (only 2 keys right now) that gets passed back into jQuery and echo's it into a `<p>` tag. I can call it by writing all of the data, but whenever I try to access a single key in the data (keep in mind its an array) it just returns either blank, or `}`. Here's my code.

HTML/JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Username Checker</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Username Checker</h1>
            <input type="text" id="name" />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <hr />
            <br />
            <p id="status"></p>
        </center>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('input#submit').on('click', function() {
                var name = $('input#name').val();
                if ($.trim(name) != '') {
                    $.post('status.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= data[0];
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

status.php

```
<?php
function remoteStatusCode($url){
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($httpcode == 404) {
        $httpcode = "<span style='color:red;'>".$httpcode;
        $httpcode .= "</span>";
    }
    else {
        $httpcode = "<span style='color:green;'>".$httpcode;
        $httpcode .= "</span>";
    }
    return $httpcode;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];

$status = array(
    'youtube' => remoteStatusCode('https://www.youtube.com/user/'.$name),
    'deviantart' => remoteStatusCode('http://'.$name.'.deviantart.com/'),
);

echo json_encode($status, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

Please don't tell me my code is vulnerable for attack or anything because I'm fully aware I haven't added any checks due to the fact its still in beta and I have no plans for releasing it yet.

Comment: _keep in mind its an array_ - I don't think so. Try `data.youtube`, or really just do `console.log(data)` in your ajax callback to see what the data looks like.

Comment: @JasonP It returns undefined and console returns this {"youtube":"<span style='color:red;'>404</span>","deviantart":"<span style='color:green;'>200</span>"} (the same as if I were to just call data)

Comment: If `data` is `{"youtube":"<span style='color:red;'>404</span>","deviantart":"<span style='color:green;'>200</span>"}`, then `data.youtube` should be `<span style='color:red;'>404</span>`: http://jsfiddle.net/PABaW/

Comment: It returns undefined, even in console

Comment: My fiddle shows that it works, can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: in the post callback, try explicitly converting the response to json before accessing the data. the php isn't setting the content type to application/json, so the result is just a string.

Comment: I tried to convert the raw data (before passing it into an array) into encoded data, but it when I tried it, it didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

in the post callback, try explicitly converting the response to json before accessing the data. the php isn't setting the content type to application/json (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-content-type-http-header-for-json), so the result is just a string.

```
$.post('status.php', {name: name}, function(data){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= obj.youtube; 
});
```

Comment: obj[0] returns undefined or obj.youtube returns undefined?  if the data is coming back as `{"youtube":"<span style='color:red;'>404</span>","deviantart":"<span style='color:green;'>200</span>"}` and you're parsing it into a json object, you access it as obj.propertyname.  look: http://jsfiddle.net/CwuWv/

Comment: I was using the native innerHTML = obj.youtube and that wasn't working, but as soon as I switched over to jQuery .html() it worked. Strange...